# Windows batch file: waiting between steps in a <for> statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to use a `for` statement in a Windows batch file ("File A") to call another program ("File B") for each .pdv (Procoder DV, not part of the problem) file in a particular directory. I want File A to wait until File B has finished running on the first .pdv file before it asks File B to run on the next .pdv file, but instead, all the calls to File B are happening at once. Here's File A:.

```
for %%X in (*.pdv) do (start /wait /b "My title" "File B" %%X)
```

Is there a way to get the calls to File B to happen sequentially (and if so, what is it)?

Comment: Is the program (File B) even executing?  Does "File B" contain the whole path to the program?

Comment: yes, that part works fine- thanks for checking though-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the program that process .pdv files instead of calling start e.g.

```
for %%X in (*.pdv) do (pdv_processor.exe "%%X")
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried it that way first, but clearly I hadn't... everything's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this you are able to wait a certain time by calling the ping command.
Wait 5 seconds:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5>nul
```